# Unable to get multiple notification clicked data

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I am displaying multiple notifications using different ids to the notification. But I am unable to get clicked notification information in other activity. Please help me with some example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Status Bar Notification feature displays a persistent notification on the status bar of your Android device. This notification can be dismissed when the user has read it, and thus this makes it a good tool for delivering notifications to the users to respond at their convenience

The link that follows may help you
https://mobiforge.com/design-development/displaying-status-bar-notifications-android

Comment: IN this they didn't give anything about multiple noifications handling. Please provide regarding information.Thanku